# How to use the Java SASL API and CRAM-MD5

Tags: java, authentication, sasl, challenge-response

I'm currently playing with the Java SASL API and I wrote a little program to simulate a challenge response sequence using CRAM-MD5. However, I'm unsure about how to do this, as SaslClient and SaslServer only have methods evaluateChallenge(...) and evaluateResponse(...). I would expect SaslServer to have a method like issueChallenge(...) or something like that, but it has not. So what is the correct way to do this?

Below you find my (not working) code.

```
    package mypackage;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
    import javax.security.sasl.AuthorizeCallback;
    import javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
    import javax.security.sasl.SaslClient;
    import javax.security.sasl.SaslException;
    import javax.security.sasl.SaslServer;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SaslException {

  new Main().start();
 }

 private static class ClientHandler implements CallbackHandler {

  @Override
  public void handle(Callback[] cbs) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
   for (Callback cb : cbs) {
    if (cb instanceof NameCallback) {

     System.out.println("Client - NameCallback");

     NameCallback nc = (NameCallback)cb;
     nc.setName("username");
    } else if (cb instanceof PasswordCallback) {

     System.out.println("Client - PasswordCallback");

     PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback)cb;
     pc.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
    }
   }
  }
 }

 private static class ServerHandler implements CallbackHandler {

  @Override
  public void handle(Callback[] cbs) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
   for (Callback cb : cbs) {
    if (cb instanceof AuthorizeCallback) {

     System.out.println("Server - AuthorizeCallback");

     AuthorizeCallback ac = (AuthorizeCallback)cb;
     ac.setAuthorized(true);

    } else if (cb instanceof NameCallback) {

     System.out.println("Server - NameCallback");

     NameCallback nc = (NameCallback)cb;
     nc.setName("username");

    } else if (cb instanceof PasswordCallback) {

     System.out.println("Server - PasswordCallback");

     PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback)cb;
     pc.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
    }
   }
  }
 }

 private void start() throws SaslException {

  byte[] challenge;
  byte[] response;

  ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
  ServerHandler serverHandler = new ServerHandler();

  SaslClient sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(new String[] { "CRAM-MD5" }, null, "my_server", "FQHN", null, clientHandler); 
  SaslServer ss = Sasl.createSaslServer("CRAM-MD5", "my_server", "FQHN", null, serverHandler);

  // Challenge response sequence (not working)
  challenge = ss.evaluateResponse(null);
  response = sc.evaluateChallenge(challenge);
  ss.evaluateResponse(response);

  if (ss.isComplete()) {
   System.out.println("Authentication successful.");
  }
 }
}
```

Greetings, Fred

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the above code working by changing one line

from

```
challenge = ss.evaluateResponse(null);
```

to

```
challenge = ss.evaluateResponse(new byte[0]);
```

The javadoc for evaluateResponse() says

> this method is called to prepare an appropriate next challenge to submit to the client

So I guess from the above, there is no need for a `issueChallange()` method, `evaluateResponse()` takes care of issuing the response.